# In-app purchase interrupt due security questions: didn't get to SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've have an app in the store already and a small (<1%) of the users complains about the in-app payment that it doesn't work. It seems that if a user is asked to add a creditcard OR to fill in their security questions the process dies somehow. The user will be redirected to the App store to do the action and after they finish they will be redirected to our app.

The user can show me their receipt and tells me the money is already transferred.

The in-app purchase is a non-autorenewable subscription. After the user did the apple transaction we store the information on our server to keep track of the payments and the date when the purchase expires.

It seems to me that the SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased isn't called is this kind of situation.

My code:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            {
                NSLog(@"Purchasing Product From Store!");
            }
            break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            {
                 NSLog(@"Purchased Product From Store! %@", transaction.description);
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                if(buyProductBlock != nil)
                {
                    buyProductBlock(TRUE, nil);
                    buyProductBlock = nil;
                }
            }
            break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            {
                //SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored is only issued after you call restoreCompletedTransactions.
                NSLog(@"Restored");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            }
            break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            {
                NSLog(@"Purchase failed %@ %@", transaction.payment.productIdentifier, transaction.payment.debugDescription);
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];

                if(buyProductBlock != nil)
                {
                    if (transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
                        buyProductBlock(FALSE, nil);
                    else
                        buyProductBlock(FALSE, transaction.error.localizedDescription);
                    buyProductBlock = nil;
                }

            }
            break;


            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following:

```
Test an Interrupted Transaction

Set a breakpoint in your transaction queue observer’s paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: method 
so you can control whether it delivers the product. Then make a purchase as usual in the test 
environment, and use the breakpoint to temporarily ignore the transaction—for example, by 
returning from the method immediately using the thread return command in LLDB. Terminate and 
relaunch your app. Store Kit calls the paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: method again shortly 
after launch; this time, let your app respond normally. Verify that your app correctly delivers 
the product and completes the transaction.
```

And the result is that the paymentQueue:updatedTransactions isn't get called after restarting the app.

Perhaps that's what my problem is ?

Thanks,
Sjoerd Perfors

edit:

Since I kill the block (buyProductBlock = nil) is it possible that first I get a SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed and when the user returns to the app I wil get a  SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased but because of the block it wont get called?

Comment: I am not sure, but it looks like you may be calling finishTransaction a bit early. Where do you actually record that the subscription has been purchased?  You shouldn't call finishTransaction until the record of the purchase has been saved successfully in your app and/or server.

Comment: buyProductBlock saves a boolean in the userdefaults at first before syncing to the server; so that should never fail if you ask me ? But is it possible that it's first SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed and then SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased ?

Comment: Still, Apple's documentation states that  you should not call finishTransaction until after you have activated the purchase on your app. It may not fix your issue but you shouldn't call finishTransaction until buyProductBlock completes

Comment: Alright, thanks Paul: I'm going to change that.

Answer (score 0):

My problems were:

- As Paulw11 mentiond: You only need to finish transactions after the product is actually synced with the server. I rewrote this stuff.
- In my block code I had an statement which was incorrect causing the product not to be synced with the server. This was actually my main error and was caused by my own code and not displayed in this question.
- Add the "addTransactionObserver" when your app starts, this will cause any unfinished transactions to be hit the paymentQueue method.

Everyone should read: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html